# how to generate histogram in pandas with x-axis labels from column?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('{"genre":{"0":"Drama","1":"Comedy","2":"Action","3":"Thriller"},"count":{"0":1603,"1":1200,"2":503,"3":492}}')
```

Is there a pandas one-liner/fast way to generate a histogram where bars are based on the "count" column, and x-axis labels are the "genre" column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can select the columns to be used with the `x` and `y` keyword arguments. You also select the kind of plot you want, in this case a hist, using `kind='bar'`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_json('{"genre":{"0":"Drama","1":"Comedy","2":"Action","3":"Thriller"},"count":{"0":1603,"1":1200,"2":503,"3":492}}')

df.plot(x='genre', y='count', kind='bar', legend=False)

plt.show()
```

Note that I've also used `legend=False` to remove the legend, you could leave this in if you so wish.

[image]

Comment: Extremely helpful...best example in within the set of few SO answers about this general topic.