# How do I set x and y axis labels for pandas histograms?

Tags: python, pandas

You would think this is Google-able but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Could you show data you want to plot and the function you would like to use?

Comment: This might be helpful:
[how-to-generate-histogram-in-pandas-with-x-axis-labels-from-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230866/how-to-generate-histogram-in-pandas-with-x-axis-labels-from-column?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting axis labels for histogram pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832675/setting-axis-labels-for-histogram-pandas)

Answer (score 5):

`pandas`' `plot` function uses `matplotlib`, so you can use the `matplotlib` functions `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel`

```
plot = df.plot(x="Some Data",y="Other Data",kind="hist")
plot.set_xlabel("X")
plot.set_ylabel("Y")
```